# Is there a special word/name/phrase for the money/income generated by student while he is in college?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, speech

Is there a special word/name/phrase for the money/income generated by a student while he is in college by working part time?

Comment: "money/income from odd jobs".

Comment: Sweated income?

Answer (score -1):

While not limited to students, and not always for work, the term *[stipend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stipend)* is often used

> A fixed regular sum paid as a salary or allowance.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Another definition:

> a periodic payment, esp. a scholarship or fellowship allowance granted to a student.

*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary,* found at [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stipend)

Comment: A "stipend" isn't a word usually used to describe income received from part-time work (whether by a student or not), but rather is a generally small amount paid on a regular basis for regular services performed. It also carries the implication that it is somewhat below the true value of the activity; the work being performed can be in some cases "voluntary" (such as a member of a church, or for someone studying for a degree), and the stipend is only to cover basic costs and needs.

Comment: @Cargill When I was in college (many years ago), the term *stipend* was regularly used to refer to monies paid to students who had work-study or internship assignments. The amount was usually fixed and a set number of hours were expected.

Comment: @bb: fair enough, insofar as it might relate to activities undertaken as a (senior) student within the faculty, however the OP has not stipulated whether the part-time work is of this nature, or refers to working in a restaurant or a gas station.

Answer (score -1):

*Is there a special word/name/phrase for the money/income generated by a student while he is in college by working part time?*

I don't believe there is a special word or phrase for this type of income; it is just referred to as income from part-time work, with no specific words that add the meaning of a student doing the work, rather than a non-student.